# Working with pens in Microsoft word 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, styles

So  I have a wacom tablet and pen connected to my machine, and I have microsoft office 2013 open as well. When I go to use the pen utility, I find it is still disabled. How do I enable this please?

Comment: Have you installed the drivers and does the model you have support Office 2013?